# Insert or replace value in one field based on value of another field using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, field-calculator, fields-attributes

I have sample data I am trying to visualize in ArcGIS Pro. I have one field that shows if the sample was detected or not (DetectedResult), which is either a 'Y' or 'N'. Then I have another field with the sample value results (Value). I need to be able to add a less than sign in front of every number in the "Value" field when the DetectedResult is 'N'.

Can I create a new field, or update the Value field, to show these results?

This is what I would like to end up with:

| Value | DetectedResult | ValueAndND |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.25 | N | <0.25 |
| 0.56 | Y | 0.56 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to @Hornbydd but 1-liner:

```
'<%s'%!Value! if !DetectedResult!=='N' else !Value!
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a simple field calculate. I show this below using Arcade as the scripting language (you could have done something very similar in python if you wished).

[image: Calculate Field]

Here is the Arcade script for you to copy into the tool:

```js
if ($feature.DetectedResult == 'N') {
    var res = Concatenate('<', Text($feature.Value));
}
else {
    var res = Text($feature.Value);
}
return res
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @hornbydd and @FelixIP, but an arcade oneliner

```js
    decode($feature.DetectedResult, 'N', '<','') + $feature.Value
```